# Is Pubnub a good solution for a mobile app that creates dynamic chatrooms from a server?

Tags: push, pubnub

- Channels would be created by the server when specific things happen
- The cellphones (users/devises) invited to that channel get notified in-app or by push notification.
- Users join that channel and are subscribed to it.
- Users can unsubscribe from that channel.
- Users can share gifs, photos and emoticons in the channel.

I don't think it will matter for this question, but the server is built in ruby.

Comment: The SO moderators are going to close this question because it is not a technical/code question. But the answer is YES, you can and should use PubNub.

Comment: Ah, it would be too bad. The dynamic part is what I see as the technical aspect. The server would need to create chat rooms dynamically. Pubnub or whatever solution I choose should be able to support chatroom creation via the API as well as notify all concerned devices that they can join the chat room.

Comment: Typically, the questions need to be specific. But so far, you've dodged judgement ;) If you have more questions, feel free to [contact PubNub Support](https://pubnub.com/support).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/) looks like a very good choice for a chat application.

You can have up to 100 devices and 1M messages a month for Free, or starting at $49/mo if you need more. [More on Pricing Here](https://www.pubnub.com/pricing/)

Also, Pubnub advertises Chat as one of it's top functions:

> APIs and infrastructure delivering over 30 billion chat messages a
>   month for 1000s of chat apps
>
> Developers have been building chat of all shapes and sizes with PubNub
>   for years. PubNub's Network is the best option for building innovative
>   and powerful chat applications because of the powerful chat APIs,
>   enterprise-grade security, scalability, and reliability.
>   [PubNub Chat Solutions Page](https://www.pubnub.com/solutions/chat/)

PubNub has a ChatEngine™ solution that may be what you are looking for:

> An open and extensible chat SDK and APIs for building powerful 1:1 and group chat quickly PubNub ChatEngine
>
> Build core chat features quickly, extend functionality with a rich
>   plugin library and customize with programmable Functions-as-a-Service.
>   Powered by the reliable, secure and scalable PubNub Network.

[PubNub ChatEngine™](https://www.pubnub.com/products/chatengine/)

Good Luck on your chat application! ☺